# Convolutional Autoencoder: where to place non-linearities?

Tags: neural-networks, autoencoders, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement a simple convolutional autoencoder in theano. The architecture I have in mind is:

```
in --> conv --> non-linearity --> max-pool --> upsample --> deconv --> non-linearity --> out
```

No fully connected hidden layers yet. The weights in the `conv` and `deconv` layers are tied, so really there is only one set of parameters to learn: the weights connecting `in --> conv`. Currently, this isn't working; I'm quickly getting weights that go to `nan` very quickly.

One thing that bothers me is the asymmetry of where the non-linearities are placed. Maybe the second non-linearity layer should be placed between `upsample` and `deconv`?

Can someone offer some advice? I have read similar posts on this topic, but they don't address this issue, or the problem of weights going to `nan`.

Other details: I'm using the sigmoid function for the non-linearity for now. Also, I'm doing the upsampling by inserting zeros in all the unknown locations.